# Google Sign in doesn't work only during "Internal Testing" on Google Play

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin

My application is in "Internal testing" phase and I am unable to proceed further since my Google Sign in is not working (no error messages, just loading). This is not standard issue where I missed SHA-1 and SHA-256 since it is working with Firebase App Distribution (Android), Testflight, but it's not working on Google Play.

I've tried:

- Adding SHA-1 and SHA-256 from Google Play Console (Both upload and signing key).
- Downloaded and replaced .json file.

Additional info:
In my Firebase project settings I am getting: "Another project contains an OAuth 2.0 client that uses this same SHA-1 fingerprint and package name combination", but there is no any project in my firebase or google cloud console that has same package name and signing key.

Since I am trying to publish Flutter app on my old Android Java app project, I've already deleted Firebase project that had same package name and signing key.

Could this be related to my Google sign in issue ?

I am also able to sign in to Facebook in release.

Comment: @learncode Yes I did, It was an issue with gcp project naming, projects were named similarly, check Oauth clients for your gcp projects.

Comment: @NedimKaravdic was the issue with your android package name or the GCP project name?  I'm having the same issue.  I'm moving the SHA over to a new oauth client from an old project to a new project.